# Validation Error: no updates are to be performed in Cloudformation returns error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I execute in my CI aws-cli to update CloudFormation stack, I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: No updates are to be performed.
```

No updates are seen like error hence the CI fails. Any idea how to capture this error?

Comment: What CI are you using?

Comment: I'm using Buildkite

Comment: and why does it run if there is no change to the template?

Comment: The pipeline is made of two steps for the staging and production. I could make some changes to production without modifying the staging but with this error I can't reach the production because it is blocked by the staging one

Comment: My idea is to grep the output and in the case that match to that error than change the exit code

Comment: That would work - but why is it building the stack if there is no update?

Comment: already said here. The pipeline is made of two sequentally steps one for the staging and production. I could make some changes to production without modifying the staging but with this error I can't reach the production because it is blocked by the staging one

Answer (score 7):

use `--no-fail-on-empty-changeset` along with your aws cli command.

eg:
`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ${TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH} --stack-name ${CF_STACK_NAME} --parameter-overrides ${PARAMETER_OVERRIDES} --no-fail-on-empty-changeset`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, command `aws cloudformation update-stack` does not have an option:
`--no-fail-on-empty-changeset`

but, perhaps, something like this could work:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name foo 2>&1)

RESULT=$?

if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$output"
else
  if [[ "$output" == *"No updates are to be performed"* ]]; then
    echo "No cloudformation updates are to be performed."
    exit 0
  else
    echo "$output"
    exit $RESULT
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For solution #5, we need to put output=$(aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name foo 2>&1) in if statement, otherwise the statement will return a non-zero code, and shell will exit

My enhanced version:

```
#!/bin/bash

if output=$(aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name foo 2>&1)
then
  echo "$output"
else
  RESULT=$?
  echo $output
  if [[ "$output" == *"No updates are to be performed"* ]]; then
    echo "No cloudformation updates are to be performed."
    exit 0
  else
    exit $RESULT
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Use "aws cloudformation deploy" command is better, because it can handle both create and update.